# How Do I Filters the list by refModel('Model_user') in the Models?

Tags: atk4

I am unable to find how to filter the drown down which i got by using refmodel in my model which extends model_table

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any view in toolkit you can use `setController` and `getController`. refModel fields from Model will set a proper controller for a form field. It uses type `reference`.

Once form in initialized, you can interact with controller of a field by

```
$field->getField('myfield')->getController()->addCondition('type','admin');
```

Alternatively the following might work too:

```
$field->getField('myfield')->dictionary()->addCondition('type','admin');
```